# How to change cursor on Fullcalendar columns

Tags: css, cursor, fullcalendar

**TL;DR**: I want a **cursor pointer** on **green cells** and **cursor disabled** on **grey cells**

I am building an application which use **Fullcalendar** and I face a problem I can’t solve:
I try to modify the cursor directly on cells (not events)
I tried to target the « .fc-future », « .fc-today » and «  .fc-past » fullcalendar classes and apply a style like « cursor: pointer » or « cursor: not-allowed » without any success.

**Here is a screenshot of what I have**:

[image]

Does anyone know how can I change the cursor on columns ?
Thanks for your help !

**My project**:

- Fullcalendar 2.8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your quick reply !

I couldn't figure out how to set this up as you explained in your post. 
So I found a workaround.
In Fullcalendar, I added a background event object:

```
{
  start: moment().startOf('isoWeek'), # beginning of week
  end: moment().utc().endOf('day'), # end of current day
  rendering: 'background',
  className: 'disabled-cell'
}
```

This "fake event" disable all day from beginning of week until the end of the current day.

For the cursor, I created a css class:

```
// Sass code
.disabled-cell
  background-color: gray
  opacity: 1
  &:hover
    cursor: not-allowed

.fc-view
  td
    cursor: pointer
```

Answer (score 0):

`<div class="fc-scroller-canvas">` contains two `div`s, one with the `fc-content` class and another with `fc-bg` class. You are setting background for the elements inside the `fc-bg`. Set the `cursor` CSS property for the same elements inside the `fc-bg`.

Then, in order to show the cursor through the `fc-content`, you need to set `pointer-events: none;` for the `fc-content` div. This will kind of make it transparent for the mouse pointer, so that you can mouseover or click the elements in the underlying `div`. That means you will be able to see the cursor you need.

Obviously this may disable some of the functionality that you may need, so you need to set back `pointer-events: auto;` on things that you need, such as on events themselves (if you do anything with eventClick, for example).